# Set a default image when I do not have one in my loop

Tags: php, if-statement, replace

i call an API of vehicle for the photos with a php GET, that return me an array,

i use this for for get the vehicles :

```
   $vehiculecount=count($data);
   for($x = 0; $x < $vehiculecount; $x++) { ?>
```

Now i want to if i have a return of the photo that return me the photo, else that return me a special "noPhoto"photo in my folder

I do this :

```
    <?php
$photo = $data[$x][gallery][0][big];
if ($photo=null) {
       $photo = img/noPhoto.png;


else {
            $photo = $photo;


 echo " $photo";

                                      }
  }
endif;
?>
```

Here the HTML :

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $photo;?>" alt="">
```

I have actualy a error 500 when i use it. So i have primary a syntax error and i cant fixe it

FIXED CODE (not working) :

```
<?php
$photo = $data[$x][gallery][0][big];
if (! $photo) {
       $photo = 'img/noPhoto.png';

else {
            $photo;

                                      }
  }

?>
```

Comment: Why did you put an `echo` at this line `$photo = echo $data[$x][gallery][0][big];`?

Comment: my mistake didnt see sorry !

Comment: Also note that your code _will not run_ - you've got two closing `}` plus an `endif`, and only _one_ opening `{`.....

Comment: Get error reporting working.  500 errors are difficult to troubleshoot.  Also, **do not keep changing your question** as you get feedback.  This is not a "keep working with me until I get it solved" site.  Additionally, my comment earlier about your code _not running_ is likely why you're getting 500 errors.... please review.

Comment: I change the title earler before all the answers, then i'm actualy try to do your recommandation in my code, please wait a tittle :) and thx for your help

Comment: I'm referring to all the code changes you are making.  The answers / feedback you are getting are now _irrrelevant_ because you've changed the code in the question multiple times now.

Comment: and actualy in my code i have nothing for return other of "error 500", du you know how add this?

Comment: Ok i understand what you mean, i put the old code so

Comment: my actual code is `$photo = $data[$x][gallery][0][big];
if (! $photo) {
    $photo = 'img/noPhoto.png';

else {
   $photo = $photo;

           }
  }` and i have the same error, i dont know how see more of this error

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in you code.
Here is repaired code.

```
$photo =  $data[$x]['gallery'][0]['big'];
if ($photo === null) {
   $photo = 'img/noPhoto.png';
}
```

Comment: What is the syntax error? How did you fix it? What did it do before that is different now?

Comment: "$photo = null" sets variable $photo with value null and string has to be in quotes

Comment: I knew that difference is obvious...explaination is added

Comment: It's obvious to you and me, we spotted it immediately.  _It is not obvious_ to the OP, otherwise you wouldn't have to answer.  So a good answer contains additional information that explains what's going on, for both the OP, as well as future visitors.

Comment: Thx for the help , i edit my post with the new code, that return me error 500

Comment: You didnt fixed "$data[$x][gallery][0][big]" part. You have to add quotes to strings like this: $data[$x]['gallery'][0]['big']

Comment: And part "else {$photo = $photo;}" is redundant because if you have $photo variable, than you dont have to set it once again.

Comment: If you use echo on single variable you dont have to write quotes(echo " $photo";). **echo $photo;** is better.

Comment: its not strings, its array,  i have a code like this and its worked, i dont understand why put ''